# How to properly make rest api endpoint when I want to delete resource and sub-resources or just resource?

Tags: rest

In my system I have two resources `packages` and `debts`, `packages` can contain multiple `debts`. Now I prepare api to delete `packages` resource, but I need to have two options available:

- Delete `packages` and related `debts` - after this action deleted resources will be not visible in the system,

Here, I'm, thinking about simple `router.delete('/packages/:token')`

- Delete `packages` but unpin related `debts` - after this action `packages` will be removed but `debts` will be updated to loose connection to deleted package, and `debts` will be available in the system for another actions.

Here I had problem, I'm think of creating `post` endpoint with action in path, something like, `router.post('/packages/:token/remove/unpin')`. But it is probably not the best rest api.

I hope, this is clear. Thank you for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading this nice post http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api, I decided to create endpoint like this `router.delete('/packages/:token/unpin')` , this will tell that I need to delete package, but `unpin` action will give me a hint that I need to unpin debts before delete packages.

In the mention post there is nice section to my problem:

> **What about actions that don't fit into the world of CRUD operations?**
>
> This is where things can get fuzzy. There are a number of approaches:
>
> 1. Restructure the action to appear like a field of a resource. This works if the action doesn't take parameters. For example an activate action could be mapped to a boolean activated field and updated via a PATCH to the resource.
> 2. Treat it like a sub-resource with RESTful principles. For example, GitHub's API lets you star a gist with `PUT /gists/:id/star` and unstar with `DELETE /gists/:id/star`.
> 3. Sometimes you really have no way to map the action to a sensible RESTful structure. For example, a multi-resource search doesn't really make sense to be applied to a specific resource's endpoint. In this case, `/search` would make the most sense even though it isn't a resource. This is OK - just do what's right from the perspective of the API consumer and make sure it's documented clearly to avoid confusion.